# Multiple Buttons Each with Unique Counter

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, ejs

So I dynamically create a number of buttons and I want to make a separate counter for each one. I am not sure how to differentiate between buttons as they will all end up having the same variable and id. This is what I have so far:

```
<script>   
    let count = 0;
    function addOne() {
        count += 1
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count
    }
</script>
    
<% for (let ele of elements) { %>
    ...
    // More html elements
    ...
    <button onclick="addOne()" type="button">Click Here!</button>
    <span id="count">0</span> 
    ...
    // More html elements
    ...
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the id property of span, they cannot be same at same time

```php
<% for (let ele of elements) { %>
    <button onclick="addOne(this)" type="button">Click Here!</button>
    <span>0</span> 
<% } %>
```

```js
function addOne(button) {
    console.log(button.nextElementSibling.innerHTML)
    var spanEle = button.nextElementSibling;
    var old = parseInt(spanEle.innerHTML)
    spanEle.innerHTML = old + 1;
}
```